# How can I transfer a stacktrace betwen Scala ExecutionContexts?

Tags: scala, mdc

I have written a small utility wrapper around the Scala `ExecutionContext` to enable transfer of MDC contexts across `Future` instances. It works as expected but an undesired side-effect is that we now don't seem to get stack traces that go across `Future`s. How can I ensure that the stack trace is propagated along with the MDC?

Here's my code for reference:

```
import org.slf4j.MDC

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._


object MdcOps {

  implicit class ExecutionContextExt(value: ExecutionContext) {
    def withMdc: ExecutionContext = new MdcExecutionContext(value)
  }

  def withMdc[A](mdc: Map[String, Any], replace: Boolean)(doIt: => A): A = {
    val currentMdcContext = getMdc
    val newMdc = if(replace) mdc else mdc ++ currentMdcContext
    try { setMdc(newMdc); doIt }
    finally { setMdc(currentMdcContext) }
  }

  def setMdc(mdc: Map[String, Any]): Unit = {
    if(mdc.isEmpty) {
      MDC.clear()
    } else
      MDC.setContextMap(mdc.view.mapValues(_.toString).toMap.asJava)
  }

  def getMdc: Map[String, String] = Option(MDC.getCopyOfContextMap).map(_.asScala.toMap).getOrElse(Map.empty)
}

class MdcExecutionContext(underlying: ExecutionContext, context: Map[String, String] = Map.empty) extends ExecutionContext {
  override def prepare(): ExecutionContext = new MdcExecutionContext(underlying, MdcOps.getMdc)
  override def execute(runnable: Runnable): Unit = underlying.execute { () =>
    MdcOps.withMdc(context, replace = true)(runnable.run())
  }
  override def reportFailure(t: Throwable): Unit = underlying.reportFailure(t)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is *hard*. ZIO implemented it - see: https://www.slideshare.net/jdegoes/error-management-future-vs-zio from slide 53 to see the result - but creation of stacks, and passing it around causes [performance penalty x2.4](https://www.iteratorshq.com/blog/benchmarking-functional-error-handling-in-scala/#comment-350).

Since you cannot change API to e.g. generate stack trace in compile times using macros (using e.g. [sourcode](https://github.com/lihaoyi/sourcecode) library), on each `.map`/`.flatMap` you would have to create a stack trace, remove irrelevant frames from it, maybe combine it with frames from previous context and set it in MDC. Putting technical details aside - this is hard to get right and heavy weight, more like a material for a whole library than simple utility. If it could be done cheaply this would be a build in.

If you are very interested in it, either pick ZIO or analyze how it implements it - from what I see it required a lot of effort and building this functionality into the library, and even then it causes performance penalty. I can only imagine that penalty by using JVM stack traces and passing them around would be even greater.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks nonetheless! Would it be possible to work around it by somehow catching "inner" exceptions and wrap them in exceptions with the "outer" stacktrace?

Comment: I made some attempt to handle this some time ago - it basically required me to: take implicit from [sourcecode](https://github.com/lihaoyi/sourcecode) in my own wrapper around Future/IO on `.map`, `.flatMap`, then use it enrich exceptions thrown with some context. But I have some serious doubts about such approach and I cannot say I would recommend anyone else to use it.